# TFS collection is over 7 TB in 3 months, how to slim it?

Tags: tfs

My customer is using TFS 2018 update 1. and since all data are put into TFS, including work item/code/document/build artificatest/test case/test case results. the TFS collection is getting large very quickly. so we are afraid of the potential performance issue for such scale.

We want to make sure whether TFS have some limit for collection DB size, and best practice to optimize such size. I just find some old document against TFS 2015 and older version. Where can I find latest documents? Thanks.

1) ways to shrink the TFS collection database？ is there a limit for TFS collection DB size? or best practice to manage it?

2)  Insight to the Database usage, which part has most space, the code/build/test/?
3)  Best practice to monitor and optimize TFS database.

Comment: Did you set retention policies for things like build artifacts and test attachments?

Comment: yes, we did. both for build and test result. and it is still so large)

Answer (score 5):

**Build results**

Not just build results, but often overlooked the actual build records can take up a considerable amount of data. Use tfsbuild destroy (XAML) to permanently delete the build records. In the past, I've encountered clients who had 1.8 million "hidden" builds in their database and removing them shaved off quite a considerable amount of data. These records were kept around for the warehouse.

**Old team projects**

Of course, destroying old team projects can give back a lot of data. Anything you don't need to send to azure helps. You could also consider splitting the collection and to leave behind the old projects. That will give you the option to detach that collection and store it somewhere, should you ever need that data again.

**Redundant files**

Deleted branches are a very common hidden size hog. When deleting things in TFVC, they are not actually deleted, they're just hidden. Finding deleted files and especially old development or feature branches can give you back a lot of data. Use tf destroy to get rid of them.

You may also want to look for checked in nuget package folders, those can quickly rack up a lot of space as well.

**Test Attachments**

Ohh yes, especially when you use test attachments, these can grow like crazy, depending on your TFS version either use the built-in test attachment cleanup features or use the Test Attachment Cleaner from the TFS power tools [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power).

**XAML Builds**

The build definitions themselves won't take a lot of db space, but the build results may. But those have been covered in a previous section.

**Be sure to run the cleanup jobs**

TFS often doesn't directly prune data from the database, in many cases it just marks stuff as deleted for latest processing. To force the cleanup to happen immediately, run the following stored procedures on your Project Collection database:

```
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1
```

You may have to run the following command multiple times, the last parameter is the batch size, if there are more items to prune than the  passed in number, you will have to run it multiple times

```
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000
```

Very useful article with more ways to reduce the TFS DB size:
[Click Here](https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/)